# How to use batch trained model, to predict on single input?

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I have RNN model that have been trained on Dataset:

```
train = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((data_x[:train_size],
                          data_y[:train_size])).batch(batch_size).repeat()
```

model:

```
    model = tf.keras.Sequential()
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.GRU(units=lstm_num_units,
                                   return_sequences=True,
                                   kernel_initializer='random_uniform',
                                   recurrent_initializer='random_uniform',
                                   bias_initializer='random_uniform',
                                   batch_size=batch_size,
                                   input_shape = [seq_len, num_features]))
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.LSTM(units=lstm_num_units,
                                   batch_size=batch_size,
                                   return_sequences=True,
                                   input_shape = [seq_len, num_features]))
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Flatten())
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=dence_units))
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dropout(drop_flat))
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=out_units))
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Softmax())   

    model.compile(loss="sparse_categorical_crossentropy",
            optimizer=tf.train.RMSPropOptimizer(opt),
            metrics=['accuracy'])

 model.fit(train, epochs=EPOCHS,
                        steps_per_epoch=repeat_size_train,
                        validation_data=validate,
                        validation_steps=repeat_size_validate,
                        verbose=1,
                        shuffle=True)
                        callbacks=[tensorboard, cp_callback])
```

I need to do prediction on single input of seq_len, but looks like my input have to be of a batch size:

```
ar = np.random.randint(98, size=[batch_size, seq_len])
ar = np.reshape(ar, [batch_size, seq_len, 1])
prediction = model.m.predict(ar)
```

Is there a way to make it work on a single input of shape [1, seq_len, 1]?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, simply rebuild the model without a batch size in the first layer.

Copy the weights of the old model.

```
newModel.set_weights(oldModel.get_weights())
```

The purpose of the batch size only exists in `stateful=True` models to keep consistency between batches.

Even though, there is no mathematical change due to batch size.

Comment: Thank you. Your comment helped me to figure out the issue. I can rebuild the model without batches or even do original model without specified batch_size, since it will be deducted from Dataset.

Comment: Batch size is defined in `fit` only (unless you're using `stateful=True`). The default value is 32 and it only exists for training.

Comment: If you feel this answer solved your question, please mark it as answered :)

Comment: According to the error msgs I was getting, I cannot use batch_size in `fit` with `tf Dataset`.  Another place where I defined `batch_size` was in first layer, so I just removed it. Now, model accepts arbitrary `batch_size`; where in training part I specify it as 64 in `tf.data.Dataset` and in prediction it is just one. Thank you to pointing me in correct direction.